# Creating linear motion using motor

Tags: bluetooth, motor

I am trying to make a smart lock for bicycles. This lock can be controlled with the help of smartphones. For the purpose, I am using an Arduino interfaced with HC-05 Bluetooth Module which receive commands from an Android smartphone.

The overall project is almost over, except the actual lock. I want to create a lock with a pin which can be slide between the spokes of the wheel to cease the motion of the wheels. I can't find any product in the Indian market. Can you please suggest any product available or how to make one myself?

> I've seen the solenoid locks but their stroke is too small to make a meaningful lock out of it.

Your help will be well appreciated.

Comment: Is it a proof of concept, or does the lock really have to be solid and temper proof?

Comment: You may find [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) useful for questions like this.

Comment: I just have to show it as my college project @Paul

Comment: As a demonstration, you could show an servo that rotates and pushes a pin between the wheels. Or modify a regular lock in a way that you can drive it with a motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pin that slides between the spokes should be just a metal bar that accepts your "small" pins in the ends to hold it in place.  Try looking at it from a different perspective and I think you will find a lot more suitable products.

You could use a worm gear, but this would be susceptible to bruit force attacks (literally) and would be easier to break.

Have you considered what happens when the power fails?  Does the lock lock or unlock?  If it unlocks on a power fail then it will be quite easy to open.  If it remains locked on a power fail then its not very user friendly, you would have to carry spare batteries and changing tools with you.

Sorry, but it is easy to poke holes in other peoples designs.

Comment: I like your suggestions @Matt, but it won't be a end product. I just have to show a working model for my college project.